# Render Ember.js Templates using Underscore.js

Tags: ember.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to render the templates in ember.js on HTML. Can the templates in ember.js be rendered using underscore.js?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it may be possible but you should use handlebars for the templates. In Ember the integration of handlebars is deep into the view layer. The also have the data binding system built on top it ([metamorph.js](https://github.com/tomhuda/metamorph.js/)).

The ember team is also working on [HTMLBars](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars) which should speed up rendering and simplify the data binding system. The current word right now is that, upgrading handlebars template to HTMLBars will be very simple maybe even without any modification.

This [post](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1624) should give you some more useful information on using other templating engines.